# Incorrect value returned by Thread.interrupted() - Why?

Tags: java, multithreading

If you execute the following code, you will see the thread is `interrupted`, however, `Thread.interrupted()` will return `false`

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        wait();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println(Thread.interrupted());
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();

        t.interrupt();
        for (;;) {
        }

    }
}
```

Please help me understand why it is `false`, Instead it should be `true`

Comment: I would strongly recommend you read [The secrets of Concurrency](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue146.html) and specifically the _The Law of the Sabotaged Doorbell_.

Answer (score 4):

The [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) are a wonderful thing...

> Throws: 
>   **InterruptedException** - if any thread
>   interrupted the current thread before or while the current thread was
>   waiting. The ***interrupted status of the current thread is cleared when
>   this exception is thrown***.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `t.interrupt()`, the `wait()` method throws an `InterruptedException`, yes, but only because internally it is periodically checking for interruptions by means of calling `Thread.interrupted()`.
If you check the API for this last method, you can read:

> [`public static boolean interrupted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted())
>   Tests whether the current thread has been interrupted. **The interrupted status of the thread is cleared by this method. In other words, if this method were to be called twice in succession, the second call would return `false`** (unless the current thread were interrupted again, after the first call had cleared its interrupted status and before the second call had examined it).

Which is exactly what is happening to you.

This is the reason why some articles like [this one from IBM DeveloperWorks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/index.html) recommend to reset the interrupted flag every time we catch `InterruptedException` but don't plan on doing anything about the interruption itself:

> When a blocking method detects interruption and throws `InterruptedException`, it clears the interrupted status. If you catch `InterruptedException` but cannot rethrow it, you should preserve evidence that the interruption occurred so that code higher up on the call stack can learn of the interruption and respond to it if it wants to. This task is accomplished by calling `interrupt()` to "reinterrupt" the current thread.